# Should simulation from a student-t copula distribution yield the input correlation matrix

Tags: simulation, copula

I am using mathematica to simulate random variates from a student-t copula distribution. Assuming that I input in the correlation matrix R, after generating a certain number of random variates, should the correlation matrix formed by my simulations fit to the initial correlation matrix R.

My results have indicated lack of fit, but I am unsure if this is true or if I am simply not generating enough results.

Is there any theory behind this?.

Comment: Are you using Gaussian copula? Are we talking about Pearson correlation?

Comment: I am not using the Gaussian copula, but the student T copula. I could easily switch between the 2. And yes, we are talking about the standard Pearson correlation

Comment: Copulas convey only and entirely the dependency structure. Correlation matrices convey information about a mix of linear dependence ($E(XY)\lesseqgtr E(X)E(Y)$) and marginal distributions. So probably you have some poor specification of the marginal distributions.

Comment: Great insight Horst. What if my specified marginal distributions are known to be correct (say, based on empirical information). What other factors could cause the discrepency between the input correlation matrix and the simulated correlation matrix.

Comment: @HorstGrünbusch but what about the Gaussian copula which is parameterized by the correlation matrix?

Comment: How are you judging that 'lack of fit'?

Comment: Well it is just a very crude look at it. But the elements of the simulated correlation matrix are very different to those of the input correlation matrix. It is interesting to note however that the correlations between the smaller elements of the simulated vectors are the ones with the most discrepancies.

Comment: @Jim: Do you call empirical information something you don't have a proof for? Statistics is a branch of mathematics.

Comment: @ssdecontrol: If the marginal distributions are not normally, then rather not. You can't change the marginals only on one side of Sklar's theorem and expect that the equality would still hold. Note that correlations are not invariant to nonlinear monotonous transformations.

Comment: @HorstGrünbusch well exactly. That's why I'm not sure what you mean about copulas conveying "only and entirely" the dependence structure.

Comment: @ssdecontrol: Sklar's theorem decomposes a joint distribution into the marginals and the copula. The marginals do not convey information about the dependency because dependency is a property of the preimages of a random variable, of the $\sigma$-algebra. The copula does map this.

Comment: @Horst: Well the marginal distributions are chosen based past data and beliefs. It is true that there is no hard proof, but it seems that the marginals chosen do fit the data

Comment: Oh, you didn't write about real data. If you use real data, you should not expect any reliable results in statistics. ;)

Comment: I understand I won't get perfect results, but the fact that the input correlation matrix is so different to the simulated correlation matrix is baffling.

Comment: It looks like you are abusing the system by making inconsequential edits in order to promote your question, Jim. Please stop doing that.  If it continues the question will be deleted.  Instead, visit our [help pages](http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/no-one-answers) for some constructive suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with Mathematica's copula functions. If this were Matlab, then you would have to provide the parameters to t-copula. These parameters wouldn't have been Spearman correlation coefficients. That's the reason I asked if you were using Gaussian copula and Spearman, which does use Spearman correlation matrix as input.

Matlab's t-copula uses [correlation parameters](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/copulaparam.html) which it gets from rank correlation coefficients, not Spearman. The other way to fit copulas is to fit them strauight to data with [copulafit](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/copulafit.html) function. This way if you additionally calculate Spearman correlation matrix, the simulated numbers will be close to it. They will *not* converge though.

Comment: Is there a reason why they would not converge. I have tried using Gaussian copula as well and that has yielded similar results to the t-copula.

Comment: @aksakal "*which it gets from rank correlation coefficients, not Spearman*" --- Spearman correlation is a rank correlation coefficient. Which other rank correlation coefficient do you mean? Kendall?